# counting up in list.generate, short flutter question

Tags: list, flutter, dart, count

i recently started learning flutter and dart, so my apologies if this is a really simple problem, i am trying to generate a list with values from another list, as follows:

```
List transactions = List.generate(15, (index)=>{
“name”: names[1],
“dp”: “assets/cm1.jpeg”,
});
```

but i want the numbers 1 to increase by 1 with every new entry. so the list should be outputting the names in my names list 1 by 1 and cm1.jpeg, cm2.jpeg etc. similar to the i+1 code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Is it something like this you want? ```List transactions = List.generate(15, (index)=>{
“name”: names[1 + index],
“dp”: “assets/cm${1 + index}.jpeg”,
});```

Comment: ah, of course... i didn't realise that "index" is used the same way as i does in other languages, this is exactly what i needed, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Added an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index variable to get the index of the current element you are generating. So first element will run the generate method with an index value of 0, the second will have the value 1 and so on.

With this knowledge you can write something like:

```
List transactions = List.generate(15, (index)=>{
“name”: names[1 + index],
“dp”: “assets/cm${1 + index}.jpeg”,
});
```